# Windows - Force a specific program to use an installed third party windows theme

Tags: windows, eclipse, command-line, themes

Is there a way to force a program (Eclipse Kepler in my case) in Windows 7 to use a 3rd party installed theme? I do not want to change the OS theme altogether. All other programs should use the default (Aero in my case) theme. So I am looking for some command line parameter, may be, which can dictate Eclipse to use a specific theme. Is this possible?

Here is an explanation of why I am looking for this solution - 
I wanted to completely change the look of Eclipse to a dark theme. I am using 'Oblivion' theme for Eclipse editor and 'Juno Dark' theme for other parts of eclipse. This leaves out certain scrollbars and other areas still inheriting white windows colors. For that I installed third party Windows OS themes. This solves the problem of styling Eclipse to a completely dark look... however I do not wish to change the look of the whole Windows 7, only eclipse.

Comment: I think the problem at the moment is that the Eclipse 4 `CSS` styling cannot change scroll bars etc on Windows - which is why Dark Juno has this problem.

Comment: @greg-449 You are right about not being able to change scroll bar colors... I am currently using a third party Windows 7 theme to do that. And I want that only Eclipse should use that theme.